# How to use subcovers to show that a set doesn't have measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm given this problem on problem set at college:

[image]

I approached the first part in the following way:

"Since $[a,b]$ is a closed and bounded interval, from the Heine-Borel theorem we know that it is a compact set. By definition, we know that there is a finite subcover."

This first part seems right to me. But I have the doubt if the exercise wants me to show only that there is a finite subcover or to really show one with *exactly* $j$ elements. If so, I think $I_{n_{k}} = \left(a \cdot \frac{j}{k} - 1; b\cdot \frac{k}{j} +1\right), k=1,2,...,j$ should work, right? Because $I:= \bigcup_{k}I_{n_{k}} = (a-1,b+1) \supset (a,b)$

Also, the third part seems quite easy once you have mastered the second one, and this is where i'm stuck. It's fairly intuitive, though.

I would start saying that as $[a,b] \subset (I_{n_{i}})$, $\sup(I_{n_{i}}) \geq b$ and $\inf(I_{n_{i}}) \leq a$, but I don't know how to go on. Any hints or ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: For the first part you need only show that there is a finite subcover, which you’ve done; $j$ will then be the number of sets in that subcover. You do not, however, get to say what $I_{n_k}$ is: the intervals $I_k$ are *given* to you.

Comment: Alright, nice, thanks! Just edited it. So, for the first part I'm safe. Any idea of how to go along with the second part?

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said in the comments, in $(a)$ you only need to show there is a finite subcover.

You can then use this, together with the triangle inequality, to prove item $(b)$.

In order to prove $(c)$, you have, by $(b)$, that

$$b-a \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(I_n)$$

for all open cover by intervals of the interval $[a,b]$.

Since the measure is, by definition, the infimum of the value on the right of the inequality over all such covers, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It wasn't clear for me that I could use the finite subcover I provided in order to prove part $b$, I was thinking that I should use a generic subcover. But if a I use this specific result on $c$, I don't get how it would help me, since, as far as I understand, I should prove that there's no subcover with "size" less than $b-a$ and because of that the set has not measure zero. Where's my mistake? Thanks again!